# string formating python to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, csvfix

I have a dictionary that I want to write into the CSV file. while writing the string value it becomes float. but I need the same string value in CSV file not float. any idea?

```
mydict={'date':int(20200729),'number':int(123),'code':int(707),'cipher':str('54545417e92')}
print mydict.values()
with open('formatting.csv','ab') as f:
    w=csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(mydict.keys())
    w.writerow(mydict.values())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually increase the width of the column and you'll see the format changes.

Since you are writing a csv file (which, unlike xlsx, does not contain its own styling and formatting), it's not related to Python and there's nothing Python can do to make Excel use a specific format.

Comment: yes i tried with manually, but same result. as i need csv files

Answer (score 0):

Like DeepSpace said, this comes from what excel is doing, not from what python is doing.  But from my experience, once excel has opened the file and assumed your data to be a float you cannot get that precision back. I suggest viewing your data raw by opening the .CSV file with a text editor instead of excel.

If you must open the file in excel, then there is a different way to do it. Open a blank excel document and then go to the data tab and click "From Text/CSV".  Then follow the prompts and use the wizard to import your data.  This way you can make sure the data type does not change from string to float.

EDIT - as a side note, I see that you tagged your question with "python 3.x", but in your example you use the old python 2 syntax of `print "a string"`.  Starting in python 3.0, you must use `print("a string")`.